# Webpack won't build with aws-jwt-verify

Tags: typescript, webpack, aws-lambda, aws-jwt-verify

I need to bundle node code for an AWS lambda for lambda@edge. I am unable to get by this error.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-jwt-verify/error'
```

I'm using typescript, and it compiles with TSC without complaint. However, when I try to bundle it with webpack, this error occurs. These are my packages and webpack.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.121",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.6.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1459.0",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^8.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.47.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-jwt-verify": "^4.0.0",
    "aws-lambda": "^1.0.7",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1"
  }
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),    
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
  },
  target: 'node',
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal example perhaps in the form of a repo?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the import statement in your `TypeScript` code and the actual `module structure` or  the module is not correctly installed.

- Check Module Installation

  `npm ls aws-jwt-verify`
- Check Import Statement
  `TypeScript` code has the correct import statement for `'aws-jwt-verify'.` The import statement should match the structure of the module.
- `TypeScript` Configuration: Verify  `TypeScript configuration` (typically `'tsconfig.json')` is correctly set up to include the necessary paths and modules. Ensure that the `'compilerOptions'` section includes:

  ```
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES6",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  ```
- Other Trivialities to check - typos  esp `icases` & do a `cache` clean if nothing works

  ```
   npm cache clean --force
   rm -rf node_modules
   npm install
  ```